# Psycopg2 query from encrypted table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, pgcrypto

I run into a problem w. selecting from a encrypted column from a table using `psycopg2`.
After having created a testtable using

```
create table users (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    secret_val_1 BYTEA,
    secret_val_2 BYTEA
);
```

I was able to insert encrypted values into it.
Now I am trying to query values from the table using `psycopg2` with:

```
cur.execute("""
            SELECT PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(%s::BYTEA, 'compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256')
            FROM users;
            """,
            ('secret_val_1',))
```

Now this raises an error:

```
ExternalRoutineInvocationException: Wrong key or corrupt data
```

Interestingly, when passing the values like so, it works:

```
def query_users_decrypt(col):
    cur.execute("""
                SELECT PGP_SYM_DECRYPT({}::BYTEA, 'compress-algo=1, cipher- 
                algo=aes256') FROM users;
                """.format(col),
                (col,))
```

But this is not secure for sql-injection attacks right?

Does anyone know how how to do this right? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in your query?  What is the `'secret_val_1'` that you are sending?  The `format()` version shouldn't work because you need single quotes surrounding it.  If your secret value looks like `'\xc30d040...'`, then put an `r` before it to make a raw string (e.g. `r'\xc30d040...'`.  The query is going to return a number of rows equal to the number of rows in your `users` table, each with a single column containing the decrypted form of whatever you passed in.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. I simply want to query from a table and decrypt the column `secret_val_1`. for all entries. Strangely the `format()` method works for me, but I know its unsafe. Unfortunately, using the `r'secret_val_1'` option gives me the same error. I am not sure what I am missing here...

Comment: Wow!  I see why the `format()` works now.  You are passing the literal `secret_val_1` to the format, so that substitutes the column name. I will put an answer in for you.

Comment: Sorry it might not have been clear since in my code, I wrapped the query in a function. I updated it, this is how it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format()` works because when you pass the `secret_val_1` in, it ends up looking like:

```
  SELECT PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(secret_val_1::BYTEA, 'compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256')
  FROM users;
```

What you are looking for is just the straight query:

```
  select pgp_sym_decrypt(secret_val_1, 'compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256')
    from users;
```

The parameter binding is meant for when you want to pass in a value to be used by your query.  The `secret_val_1` is not a value as it is the name of a column.

Use parameter binding for something like this:

```
cur.execute("""select pgp_sym_decrypt(secret_val_1, 'compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256' 
                 from users 
                where username = %s""", ('joeuser',))
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!